# Mount volumes .NET Core Docker

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a following `Dockerfile` to create a .NET Core 2.1 APP:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.402-sdk AS builder
WORKDIR /app
# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore ./myproject.sln
# copy everything else and build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish ./myproject/myproject.csproj -c Release -o /app/out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.4-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app/out ./
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT Production
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproject.dll"]
```

I create the Docker image and the container can be instantiated without any issues. When I try to share data between this container an another one, I then create the following `docker-compose` file:

```
version: "2"

services:
  another_app:
    restart: always
    image: another_app:latest
    container_name: another_app
    ports:
      - "4000"
    volumes:
      - shared-folder:/dist

  myproject_app:
    restart: always
    image: myproject:latest
    container_name: myproject
    volumes:
      - shared-folder:/app

volumes:
  shared-folder:
```

Configuring that way it does not work. I get a weird .NET message for that app:

```
myproject_app | Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
myproject_app |   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
another_app| 0|another-a | Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000
```

Now I found the problem goes away when I define the volume NOT in the root of the application. For example, if I do:

```
myproject_app:
    restart: always
    image: myproject:latest
    container_name: myproject
    volumes:
      - shared-folder:/app/another-folder
```

It then works. Why cannot you mount a volume at the root level of your .NET Core application and why do you get that error?

Comment: same issue here...

Comment: seeing the same issue as well. struggling to find anything online to explain it. If I do get it to run without this issue the folder isn't used for the app files like I'd expect

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have faced a similar issue and I think I know the reason why :

> Configuring that way it does not work. I get a weird .NET message for that app:
>
> ```
> myproject_app | Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
> myproject_app |   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
> another_app| 0|another-a | Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4000
> ```

This message happens because the dotnet tool couldn't find the `.dll` file so it treated it as a dotnet subcommand which then throws an error because it requires the dotnet sdk. ( since the last build only contains the runtime )

#### The Main Problem

The problem lies in the usage of the docker volume `shared-folder:/app` and `WORKDIR` being `/app`. What really happens here is that when the docker volume is connected it **overwrites** the contents of the container `/app` directory with the `shared-folder` directory in the local machine and hence it wasn't able to find the app `.dll` file and the above error happened.

This is why when you changed it to `shared-folder:/app/another-folder` it was able to able to work perfectly as it was mapped to an empty directory in the container.

Comment: It does make sense!